# host a facebook app on multiple locations (variable redirect_uri)

Tags: facebook, api, redirect

I'm currently building a facebook app integration and got stuck on error 191: The specified URL is not owned by the application. (when trying to authenticate a user)

I realize the problem is the Site URL, which was not entered. However, my problem is the fact that Facebook will only redirect users to URI's on this domain - and my app will be hosted on more than one server. 
It's a private admin app that will be sold to more than one client, and deployed to their server and domain. Thus, each client will have this app requesting redirect_uri back to their location, one will be installed on mysite1.com and another on mysite2.com

It appears that my only solution now is to create a separate app for each client (?) 
Is there a way to request login redirection to an arbitrary URI ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use that kind of a model with facebook apps. 
the facebook app allows you to add multiple domain names in the console now but it is not feasible to enter every name of every client to your application setting. 
maybe you should think of having one central system and sell subscription service to your clients